# Mysql Query to match two columns

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structure:

```
Id, SpouseId
1, 2
2, 1
```

Basically this tells if two people are married.

I need to to write a mysql query that returns Married couples in the database.

I thought first that i will just check if the SpouseId is not empty, but that is not enough, because i also need to check if the Id exists.

Answer (score 3):

Use an `INNER JOIN` against itself to return pairs where both partners exist.  This way, in order for the JOIN condition to be met, the spouse must not only be non-empty, but must also have a matching row as `Id`.  Hopefully, you don't have any instances where the `SpouseId` of a corresponding `SpouseId` is not the other `Id` (i.e A -> married to B -> married to C)

```
SELECT
   p.Id AS person,
   s.Id AS spouse
From 
  people p
  INNER JOIN people s ON p.SpouseId = s.Id
/* Should eliminate the duplicate, since one pair will always have 
   a higher id for the person than the spouse, and the other is lower. */
WHERE p.person > p.spouse
```

Note, however, that this will return 2 rows for every pair since each partner will appear both in `Id` and in `SpouseId`.

#### Update

The `WHERE` clause was added to eliminate one of  rows for each married pair.  The idea is that for each pair, there's a higher id and a lower one.  The pair with the higher id in `person` is retained, and the pair with the lower id in `person` is eliminated.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly.  You are right i do get two rows but i think that would work.  i can find a way to group both rows.

Comment: So i tried grouping the columns using the LastName column i had, but that did not work in a case of multiple married couples with the same last name.  Is there a better way to group the two rows?

Comment: @Dani It's a little silly, but I think it should work. See the `WHERE` clause added above - the idea is that of each pair, one always has the higher id for person than spouse.  This eliminates the pair where the person has the lower id than spouse (the other half)

Comment: Thanks.  that did the trick. although i was hoping i could use a Group by using the two columns. Thanks.